# Can Play 2.3.x be used without Activator (and with maven)?

Tags: java, maven, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.3

I have two related questions here.

In Play 2.2.x, the distribution was bundled as a zip file, and available for download through the maven repository http://downloads.typesafe.com/play/2.2.x/play-2.2.x.zip. This meant that you could use a pom.xml and embed play into your app without needing to use sbt. Given 2.3.x has shifted to the activator model, is it still possible to use it with maven?

And secondly, is it possible to use play 2.3.x without activator at all? (I know they have a sbt plugin for play, but that seems very complex as well).

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Activator is only needed to create the empty template project, which you could also do by hand if you know a bit about play. After that empty project is created all you need is sbt (which actually is a pretty central part of activator).

With play 2.3 the distribution model changed from the one big zip-file to regular ivy/maven dependencies, so you could possibly get all dependencies right from a maven project. The problem is that the sbt play setup does so much more: template compilation, routes DSL compilation, hot reloading, asset pipeline stuff, so I don't think maven actually is an option.

Comment: The problem is - what if I'm not familiar with the setup? I am, and I was able to set things up - added a conf, app dir et al. But what if I want to ask someone newer to do so - they'd have to just magically know all this stuff? :) That seems kind of a step back for Play.

Comment: In that case you would have to download the activator bundle, just like you before had to download the play bundle. The difference isn't really that big. A bonus is that activator can create all kinds of different Scala and Java projects, not only play projects.

Comment: Actually, activator weighs in at 355MB. Play at 100~.

Comment: The mini bundle (without all dependencies included) is 1MB

Comment: Hmm, the mini version is just an installer - it still downloads everything, including the activator, and the crappy html5 IDE that ships with it..

Comment: With the current version 1.2.8, not starting the gui but just calling "activator new" and creating a play project downloads ~20Mb on my computer

Comment: The answer to this question isn't NO. So why is this the accepted answer?

Answer (score -3):

Yes.

[Example on Github](https://github.com/alancnet/playtest)

```scala
package io.github.alancnet

import java.io.File

import play.api.{Environment, ApplicationLoader}

object PlayTest {
  class Dummy{}
  def main(args:Array[String]):Unit = {
    def startWebServer = {
      val environment = new Environment(
        new File("."),
        classOf[Dummy].getClassLoader,
        play.api.Mode.Dev
      )
      val context = play.api.ApplicationLoader.createContext(environment)
      val application = ApplicationLoader(context).load(context)

      play.api.Play.start(application)

      play.core.server.NettyServer.fromApplication(
        application
      )
    }

    startWebServer

  }
}
```

Comment: Can't se how your example explains in any way how to build a play project with maven. That it is possible to create a Play sbt project without using Activator is pretty clear from my answer.