# What to choose - sbt, maven or activator - for developing standalone command-line modules for Play?

Tags: maven, playframework, sbt, typesafe-activator

I am investigating possible frameworks for the future web-app I am tasked of building and Play framework 2.3 is pretty much sitting atop the list - however, I haven't used it until now (had used Spring and Maven in another life) and I have a particular requirement on the app itself so I wanted to hear advice/thoughts from people who have used Play so far (the language used will be Java 8).

The web-app consists of modules, some of which are stand-alone units that should be built as a jars (so that they can be accessed from command-line as a part of, say, batch script) as well as being built to function within the full-blown web-app.

Now, I've previously built apps with maven and I *could* imagine a way to do it with it but Play comes with its own build/dependency management tool (SBT) which I am unfamiliar with and don't know the capabilities of (is this even possible to achieve with SBT? How difficult would it be?).

That being said, I have done some cursory research on the subject and I know there is `play2-maven-plugin`, however the examples on the [homepage](https://code.google.com/p/play2-maven-plugin/wiki/UsagePlay23) deal with Scala (which I, as said above, unfortunately can't use).

What's certain is that I'd definitely like to escape from any "bridging" between SBT and maven - I wouldn't want to maintain two build systems and reconcile the differences between them together, that seems nightmarish.

Lastly, I've found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25040414/can-play-2-3-x-be-used-without-activator-and-with-maven) SO thread, using maven with Play 2.3 may not even be an option (SBT apparently does somehow use Maven dependencies under the hood). After all, Play was conceived as partial departure from Java EE practices so it doesn't surprise me Maven is not natively supported. Also, Play [integration](http://orrsella.com/2014/02/25/integrating-play-framework-and-maven/) with Maven proved to be troublesome.

I have no objection towards learning SBT or using just maven (if that's possible/advisable) - any of these approaches I am fine with, it's just the capabilities of SBT I am unfamiliar with (especially considering the requirement from above). Mixing SBT and maven seems frankly a bit scary and documentation on building Play with SBT seems scarce at this point.

Should I go with SBT or maven? What tutorials/docs would you recommend? Should I use Activator for getting to know SBT?

Comment: I'm curious about where you found *"SBT apparently does somehow use Maven dependencies under the hood"*?

Comment: I wish I could but I can't find it any more - essentially, the article referred to as of Play 2.3, build system is relying on Apache Ivy/Maven for dependency management; you can see some evidence of it here -> [link](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/SBTDependencies). I wish I could be more precise but that's all I remember; if I stumble upon the link again, I'll post it. EDIT: Apparently, it was here all the time - take a look at the answer in the linked SO thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NOTE** I was almost to flag the question as `unclear what you're asking`, but at the very end of it found the real questions I'm going to answer here.

### Should I go with SBT or maven?

SBT or even better [Typesafe Activator](https://typesafe.com/activator). Install it on your computer, and execute `activator new myNewCoolPlayJava8App play-java` to get started with Play and Java.

Apache Maven might be a viable option, but don't think it's going to be a time-saver (you'll be spending quite some time to get the configuration working).

### What tutorials/docs would you recommend?

The official web site of Play Framework is enough to get started with the stack (and don't get stuck) - https://www.playframework.com/documentation. I very often use it and found it very informative. When I need a bit more in-depth information I use Google or StackOverflow (under [playframework](/questions/tagged/playframework)).

### Should I use Activator for getting to know SBT?

No. SBT can live without Activator, but no vice versa. SBT's the foundation for Activator. See https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/Build:

> The Play build system uses sbt, a high-performance integrated build
>   for Scala and Java projects. Using sbt as our build tool brings
>   certain requirements to play which are explained on this page.

And from [the Activator's docs](http://typesafe.com/activator/docs) (just at the very bottom of [the page](http://typesafe.com/activator/docs)):

> Activator applications use sbt under the covers. This means that
>   anything you can do in sbt you can do with an application in
>   Activator. For instance, sbt plugins can easily be added to
>   applications in Activator just like they would normally be added.